# Error trying to deploy MERN app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I'm trying to deploy MERN stack app to Heroku, everything works fine except the landing page.
I tried every single solution I can but nothing worked.
Here is my app l[anding page](https://whispering-caverns-05689.herokuapp.com/), it displays blue screen with a button up top, if try to navigate to different routes like [/contact](https://whispering-caverns-05689.herokuapp.com/contact) or [/plans](https://whispering-caverns-05689.herokuapp.com/plans) it works fine.
I checked the logs and network requests everything is okay 200 status.
[image]

I tested the app on my machine and it worked as expected.
[image]

On Heroku it displays blue screen
[image]

Here is my server.js code

```
// Serve Static assests if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  //set Static folder
  app.use(express.static('frontUI/client/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontUI', 'client', 'build', 'index.html')
    );
  });
}
```

here is my script

```
"scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix frontUI/client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontUI/client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild":
      "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontUI/client && npm run build --prefix frontUI/client"
  },
```

My landing page route

```
<Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={matchProps => (
          <WithLayout
            {...matchProps}
            component={ServicesView}
            layout={MainLayout}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Hi, So what kind of error are you getting? Can you post error message here?

Comment: There is not error message, everything compiles normally, but the output is not as expected.